# Set up mesh network with RF Transceivers

Tags: communication, bootloader, nrf24l01+, rf, networking

I would like to set up a mesh network of Arduinos with the following features/capabilities:

- No master node
- Arduinos capable of bootloading other Arduinos through RFs
- Capable of communicating over TCP/IP
- More than 255 possible network addresses

Is this possible, or infeasible? If it is, what are some software packages that meet these requirements. I was looking at RF24Gateway, RF24Mesh, RF24Network, etc., but as far as I can tell these require having a master node, and they only support 255 IP addresses. Is this correct? I was also looking at an Optiboot clone that works with RF24 modules [here](https://github.com/nicolas-schurando/optiboot-nrf24l01) but it seems like it requires the other Arduino to be connected to a USB.

Any suggestions/clarifications are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How far have you come in reading about what functionality the NRF24L01 can support (such as addressing, network topology, etc)?

Comment: You always can make your own 'protocol' with nRF24L01, you don't have to use the Master/Slave protocol which is built in. These do not work with IP addresses, but they use addressing, not sure how many.